# Springboot: Modify query search Mongo or filter the result

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'd like to do something as simple as, using the search method in MongoRepository, get all the users in a collection only if their name doesn't start with a #.

I understand that there are 2 ways:

Modify the method:

```
@Query("{$or:[{null:?0}, {grupos:{$in:[?0]}}]}") 

Page search(String grupo, Pageable pageable);
```

Or, get all Users but then filter the list with some .stream expression. For instance: usuarios.getContent().stream().forEach(XXXXX)

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance! Ignatius

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had to add in the @Query tag the new condition $regex ->

```
@Query("{$and:[ {nombre:{'$regex' : '^((?!#).)*$', '$options' : 'i'}}, {$or:[{null:?0}, {grupos:{$in:[?0]}}]}]}")
    Page<Usuario> search(String grupo, Pageable pageable);
```